# Finding available Rooms for an specific Site and create Room reservation from XPages interface

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I need to create a mobile application where users can book a Room and send Calendar invite to selected users.

I want to create an interface where users will:

1. Select a Site
2. Select a Date and Time
3. Find Available Rooms
4. Choose a Room
5. Select attendees
6. Create Room Reservation and Calendar Invite

Can somebody point me in the right direction?
I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726007/xpages-extension-library-create-an-event-with-room-reservation-via-data-calendar), but, I'm still confused on how to get started with Rooms and Calendar API.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

ENVIRONMENT:
I'm running 9.0.1 with embedded Extension Library; I'm not using a version from openNTF

Comment: What do you mean getting started.

Comment: For starters rip open the mail template and the resource booking template and have a look

Comment: amongst other things this also highly depends on the Domino server version used. Please clarify...

Comment: @Lothar Mueller, I'm running 9.0.1 with default ExtLib

Comment: not knowing what you have tried so far it's close to impossible giving you a helpful hint. Have you tried the relevant ddwiki resources like this: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Domino_calendar_service_reference&content=apicontent or this: https://www.ibmdw.net/social/2014/03/03/two-new-articles-rest-apis-ibm-domino-9-0-1/ ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of steps you have to do to get there. The calendar API currently (to my best knowledge) doesn't expose rooms and resources. So you have to find them yourself. Steps:

1. Loop through the ($Rooms) view in names.nsf to get a list of available rooms
2. Get the server name, the NSF name, so together with "($Reservations)" you can construct the view name where all reservations are for that room
3. Keep the room name, capacity and the site, so you can show them in your UI
4. The Freetime lookup is not exposed in the API, nor is the find rooms. There's a [freetime lookup service](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino7-free-time/) you can use
5. Iterate through the rooms on the site to see what's free (of course you can disect the mail template)

Then you can create an entry using the Calendar API. Yes it is messy